# Which Format Specifier

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define calc(a,b) (a*b)/(a-b)
void calculate(){
    int a = 20, b = 10;
    printf("%f\n", calc(a+4,b-2));//output 0.00000
}
```

what to do to print the actual answer, 4.83.

Comment: how do you think this is 4.83? `(24 * 8) / (24 - 8) = 192 / 16 = 12`

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, just execute it:)

Comment: Hunter is right. If you intentionally left out the parentheses in calc() as you wrote in another comment below, then a law should be created to forcibly keep you away from any kind of compiler ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with your datatypes which are ints, not with format-specifiers. Integer division is always truncated to the whole numbers. You should consider changing your variables to float instead of int.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define calc(a,b) (a*b)/(a-b)
void calculate(){
    float a = 20.0f, b = 10.0f;
    printf("%f\n", calc(a+4,b-2));//output 0.00000
}
```

Comment: Or double (which, on many systems, is just as fast as float).

Answer (score 2):

```
#define calc(a,b) ((a)*(b))/((a)-(b))
```

Can you spot the extra parentheses?

--> `calc(a+4,b-2)` resolves to `((a+4)*(b-2))/((a+4)-(b-2))`. Correct.

Your solution without the extra parentheses:

--> `calc(a+4,b-2)` resolves to `(a+4*b-2)/(a+4-b-2)`. Which is very different!

Comment: Very good catch! While the integer division may cause rounding issues, the macro is definitely the real problem here. The expanded (a+4*b-2)/(a+4-b-2) isn't the same as the intended ((a+4)*(b-2))/((a+4)-(b-2))

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the expression first.  `calc(a+4,b-2)` is of type int, and integer division truncates.

For example, you could change the declarations to:

```
double a = 20.0, b = 10.0;
```

and then change `"%f\n"` to `"%.2f\n"` to get two decimal places.